# Notation in Steele's Stochastic Calculus

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation

Steele, Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications, p. 108, Proposition 7.13:
[image: Steele, Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications, p. 108, Proposition 7.13]
What does the notation $\tau_{u-}(\omega)$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tau_{u-}(\omega) := \lim_{t \uparrow u} \tau_t(\omega)$$
where the limit exists since $u \mapsto \tau_u(\omega)$ is increasing.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks!